# Remove query strings from static resources

Tags: performance, optimization, querystring

I am checking my website performance in [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/staging.route2fashion.com/05wRSVVS)

and I found that **Remove query strings from static resources's** GRADE are just 34% because of some of image URL content parameters like

```
Aigner.JPG?1478080241267
DKNY.jpg?1478080241292
```

[image]
this URLs also effect on **Serve resources from a consistent URL**

I am not able to find out why this is happening and how to remove query string from image URL.

**Note**
Query string only add on brand URLs others images are perform well.

Comment: Those look like cache busting query strings. Any chance those images are part of a non-core module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this script code in my brand image slider template

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#<?php echo $uniqued;?> .slider').responsiver({
                interval: <?php echo $options->delay;?>,
                speed: <?php echo $options->duration;?>,
                start: <?php echo $options->start -1;?>,
                step: <?php echo $options->scroll;?>,
                circular: true,
                preload: true,
                fx: 'slide',
                pause: 'hover',
                control:{
                    prev: '#<?php echo $uniqued;?> .control-button li[class="preview"]',
                    next: '#<?php echo $uniqued;?> .control-button li[class="next"]'
                },
                getColumns: function(element){
                    var match = $(element).attr('class').match(/cols-(\d+)/);
                    if (match[1]){
                        var column = parseInt(match[1]);
                    } else {
                        var column = 1;
                    }
                    if (!column) column = 1;
                    return column;
                }          

            });
        });
    </script>
```

The issue with **preload** when preload is enabled image URL print with a query string.